# FactoryGirl belongs_to association's uniqueness validation fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot

`create_list(:post, 3)` causes uniqueness validation to fail.

My factory that has a belongs_to association between Post and Author:

```
factory :post do
  author
end

factory :author do
  sequence(:internal_ref) { |n| n }
end
```

The `Author` model has a uniqueness validation on `internal_ref`.

**UPDATE**

After comments below that suggest cleaning the database, I have attempted to start from a brand new test database like this:

```
rake db:drop
rake db:create
rake db:schema:load
rake # to create test db and run the tests
```

And use the `database_cleaner_gem` like this in spec_helper:

```
config.before(:suite) do
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
end
```

Comment: I had the same problem. I'll be interested to hear what others come up with, but mine disappeared after I tweaked the Rspec.config database cleaner settings https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner#how-to-use

Comment: Try this post. A solution is presented, and the 'why' is in the comments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091039/how-come-factory-girl-isnt-sequencing-unique-attributes

Comment: @steel I tried using a brand new database and using the database cleaner gem, but I am not getting the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing this question. It looks like this suite was creating a list of author records in seeds.rb and was loading seeds.rb before running the test suite.